# How to partition this large MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-partitioning, large-data

I have a table that with about 1 billion rows that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ghcnddata` (
`date`  date NOT NULL ,
`TMIN`  float(6,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`TMAX`  float(6,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`PRCP`  float(6,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`SNOW`  float(6,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`SNWD`  float(6,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`station`  varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (`station`, `date`),
INDEX `date` (`date`) USING BTREE ,
INDEX `station` (`station`) USING BTREE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

All of the queries I run have a line that looks like this:

```
 WHERE `station` = "ABSUXNNSDIA3"
```

and a line that looks like this:

```
 AND `date` BETWEEN "1990-01-01" AND "2010-01-01"
```

There are about 30,000 unique values for the `station` field, and no queries refer to more than 1 station. Ideally I would like to simulate having 33,333 different tables; one per station (1 billion/30,000 = 33,333).

Initially I thought I could accomplish this by setting a `HASH index` on `station`, but apparently that is only for `MEMORY` tables. Then I thought I `PARTITION BY KEY (station) PARTITIONS 33333`, but it seems that this is far too many partitions.

What should I do in this scenario? I can't really experiment because the table is so large that any modifications take a very long time.

There is no master/slave or replication or clustering or anything fancy like that.

Comment: Are you sure, partitioning is a good idea at all?

Comment: Well, no - but if this isn't a good situation for partitioning, what is? Queries on that table take forever, but if I copy one of the 33333 stations to its own table, and query that - its fast. Is there no way to simulate this without actually making 33333 tables?

Comment: The reason it is fast with the one table does not scale to so many tables - you will have only 1/33333 of the key and pool cache as opposed to the single table.

Comment: Reversing the PK to (date, station) will hugely help index locality, you might then need to drop the date index to really use it.

Comment: I see. Ok, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Eugen What makes you say that paritioning might not be a good idea at all? When a large table can be split into pieces that do not intersect when queried, isn't that a good structure to partition?

Comment: If all are on the same disk (InnoDB tablespace) on the same machine, I suspect savings won't be that great. **Suspect** is the important word.

Comment: Did you just try partitioning with fewer partitions? If you partition by station with perhaps 8 partitions, that could help. If MySQL can then limit a query to at most 1 partition based on station ID, and use the date index after that for the range, it will at least make the data that needs to be searched (and the date index) smaller. I have not used MySQL partitioning directly, but in a sharded environment this is how we would approach it, so the same idea might work. The idea is that with 8 partitions, you have 1/8 the size of the data in one place to search.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need one partition per station. The point of HASH or KEY partitioning is that you define a fixed number of partitions, and multiple values are mapped into that partition.

```
mysql> alter table ghcnddata partition by key(station) partitions 31;
```

I choose a prime number for the number of partitions just out of habit, because it helps distribute data over the partitions more evenly if the data follows a pattern (like only odd values).

```
mysql> insert into ghcnddata (station, date) values ('abc', now());
mysql> insert into ghcnddata (station, date) values ('def', now());
mysql> insert into ghcnddata (station, date) values ('ghi', now());
mysql> insert into ghcnddata (station, date) values ('jkl', now());
mysql> insert into ghcnddata (station, date) values ('mno', now());
mysql> insert into ghcnddata (station, date) values ('qrs', now());
mysql> insert into ghcnddata (station, date) values ('tuv', now());
mysql> insert into ghcnddata (station, date) values ('wxyz', now());
```

When I run a query with `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` it tells me which partition(s) it must read.

```
mysql> explain partitions select * from ghcnddata where station='tuv';
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ghcnddata | p21        | ref  | PRIMARY,station | PRIMARY | 122     | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

We can see in this case that only partition 21 was read when I reference station 'tuv'.

Note that partitioning is not a panacea. It only helps to reduce the work of the query if you search for a *constant value* (not a variable, or a join condition, etc.) in the same column that you defined as the partitioning key.

The rows I just inserted should be roughly evenly distributed, but not *perfectly* evenly distributed. And there's no guarantee it's one `station` value per partition.

```
mysql> select table_name, partition_name, table_rows 
    from information_schema.partitions where table_name='ghcnddata';

+------------+----------------+------------+
| table_name | partition_name | table_rows |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| ghcnddata  | p0             |          1 |
| ghcnddata  | p1             |          2 |
| ghcnddata  | p2             |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p3             |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p4             |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p5             |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p6             |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p7             |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p8             |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p9             |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p10            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p11            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p12            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p13            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p14            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p15            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p16            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p17            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p18            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p19            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p20            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p21            |          2 |
| ghcnddata  | p22            |          1 |
| ghcnddata  | p23            |          1 |
| ghcnddata  | p24            |          1 |
| ghcnddata  | p25            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p26            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p27            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p28            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p29            |          0 |
| ghcnddata  | p30            |          0 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
```

P.S.: Your table's index on `station` is redundant, because that's the leftmost column of your primary key already.